# Not booting after update

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2

When trying to reboot after the 20.04 update from 19.10. I'm dual booting windows 10.

I get a timeout error

timeout waiting for device dev-disk-by...

If have tried to follow this:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/471716/timed-out-waiting-for-device-dev-disk-by-x2duuid-c829-x2dc4c1-device

However I cant access a terminal and recovery mode isnt working.

Answer (score 0):

Boot into a Live-USB Ubuntu OS and follow the steps outlined in the website you posted. That will get you a terminal to work from.

Please click [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1239762/edit) and add that vital information to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our channel to you. All facts about your system should go in the Question with [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1239762/edit) –